# how to change Textview text with button

Tags: android, string, button, random, textview

I have one textview and one button ,i coud change textview text with below code :

```
final Textview c_tv_matn;
Button c_btn_dokme;


c_btn_dokme = (button) findviewbyid(R.id.btn1);
c_tv_matn = (Textview) findviewbyid(R.id.txt1);

c_btn_dokme.setonclickListener(new OnclickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
c_tv_matn.SetText("this is second text");
});
```

But i wanna change text from String.xml and make Next Button Like this ; 
"matn_1","matn_2"matn_3"matn_4...

**STRING.XML**

```
<string name="matn_0">Hello world!</string>
 <string name="matn_1">You are hero john</string>
<string name="matn_2">you can change this world</string>
<string name="matn_3">You are so clever</string>
```

cAN YOU HELP ME TO GET RES FROM STRING AND CHANG TEXTVIEW TEXT WITH NUMBERS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cAN YOU HELP ME TO GET RES FROM STRING AND CHANG TEXTVIEW TEXT WITH NUMBERS?

You can use either `getString(int)` or `getText(int)` to retrieve a string. `getText(int)` retains any rich text styling applied to the string.
But in this case you'll use `getString(int)` that returns the string value associated with a particular resource ID. It will be stripped of any styled text information.

Sometimes you'll need a `context` like on this case that you want to do it inside a `Button` then you can get the `context` from your `View`, or if you have a global `context` in your `Activity/Fragment` you can use it also.

### Example

If I did not misunderstood, what you want is to put the text from `Strings.xml` to `TextView`, so you can do it like this :

```
final Textview c_tv_matn;
Button c_btn_dokme;
int textNumber = 1;


c_btn_dokme = (button) findviewbyid(R.id.btn1);
c_tv_matn = (Textview) findviewbyid(R.id.txt1);

c_btn_dokme.setonclickListener(new OnclickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(textNumber){
case 1:
   c_tv_matn.setText(v.getContext().getString(R.string.matn_1))
   textNumber++;
break;
case 2:
   c_tv_matn.setText(v.getContext().getString(R.string.matn_2))
   textNumber++;
break;
case 3:
   c_tv_matn.setText(v.getContext().getString(R.string.matn_3))
   textNumber++;
break;
default:
textNumber = 1;
  c_tv_matn.setText(v.getContext().getString(R.string.matn_1)
break;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `String` from `string.xml` you need a `Context`.

An `Activity` is a `Context` so, if you are in an `Activity` you can just call `getString(R.string.<the name in string.xml>)` to retrieve the `String` you need.

For example `getString(R.string.matn_0)`.

Then it can be applied to your needs:

```
c_tv_matn.SetText(getString(R.string.matn_0));
```

If you are not in an `Activity` then you need to get hold of a `Context`, probably passing it in as a parameter to the constructor of the class (and store it as an attribute) or as a parameter to the method that will do the setting of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array in an Android XML file

you need an array in string.xml. For reference please have look on below link

https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/grid_view_array.html